# Set calendar to a value from a Date variable

Tags: java, variables, date, calendar

I have a variable date1 which stores a date. I need to get the year from that. So, I want to instantiate a calendar and set its date to the one from date1. Then, I can use getYear().

How do I set the calendar

```
Date date1; //I set its value from database.
Calendar ca1 = Calendar.getInstance();
ca1.set(date1); // doesn't work
```

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: thanks ZouZou .... I had put 4 spaces before the code block but it didn't display correctly....isn't that the right way ?

Comment: Personally, I'd ditch the use of the default JDK date/time classes in favor of [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
ca1.setTime(date1);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
 cal.setTime(date1);

 int year= cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);// Here is your desired year
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`setTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29) :

> Sets this Calendar's time with the given Date.

```
ca1.setTime(date1);
```

Answer (score 1):

doing only `Date date1;` will not work because here only reference is created

you have to do `Date date1=new Date();`

Suppose **dbDate** is the date you are getting from Database

```
Date date1=new Date(dbDate);
```

then do

```
Calendar ca1 = Calendar.getInstance();
ca1.setTime(date1);
```

Comment: *"Date date1; //I set its value from database."*

Comment: @MarounMaroun i thoght OP is just creating the reference not creating the object

Comment: @javaBeginner There's no method set that can accept a Date as parameter

Comment: @ZouZou you are true,I have not noticed that.I will modify it

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar ca1 = Calendar.getInstance(); 
ca1.setTime(date1);
```